# Whether generated WCF Service Client is Synchronous or Asynchronous by default?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, asmx, webservice-client, synchronous

I am new to WCF Service. I read that both ASP.NET and WCF Services are synchronous by default. However we can implement both the ASP.NET and WCF Services asynchronously. I want to know whether the generated Web Service Client (Proxy Class) is synchronous or asynchronous by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is **synchronous**.

If you want the async method signatures, too, you need to either specify `/async` for `svcutil.exe`

```
C:\>  svcutil (some URL here)  /async
```

or you need to check the `Generate asynchronous operations` option in your `Add Service Reference` dialog in Visual Studio.

[image]

And of course - once you have generated the async methods, you also need to *call* those, obviously..... (they are called `Begin(YourMethodName)` and `End(YourMethodName)` for each of your service methods)